# WPF Растягивание панели внутри button на всё доступное место

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть Button

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource Round}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock>Сохранить</TextBlock>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="70,0,0,0">
                    <Ellipse Fill="Black" Width="5" Height="5"></Ellipse>
                    <Ellipse Fill="Black" Width="5" Height="5" Margin="5,2,-5,9"/>
                    <Ellipse Fill="Black" Width="5" Height="5" Margin="10,2,-10,10"/>
                    <Ellipse Fill="Black" Width="5" Height="5" Margin="15,6,-15,6"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Я хочу чтобы текст всегда оставался по центру, а Grid с Ellipse всегда была справа. Подскажите можно сделать компоновать элементы внутри кнопки. Сейчас если я делаю отступ с Ellipse больше то и текст убегает.
`Идея в том чтобы растянуть Grid на все доступное место у button и выравнивать элементы по разным краям`

Answer (score 0):

Решение которое мне помогло.
В дизайнере VS щелкните правой кнопкой по button и выберите правка шаблона, затем правка копии, введите желаемое наименование для шаблона и нажмите OK.

Стандартный шаблон будет добавлен в проект, теперь можно его отредактировать. Найдите в нем примерно такое место:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

И замените у

```
VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
```

замените их значения на `Stretch` теперь в button если добавить grid или stackpanel, то она может будет занимать все доступное место.
`Пример результата:`

```
<Grid>
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource Round}">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Text</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эм... Ничего не смущает? Вот внимание сюда `VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"`, что видим? А видим то, что значению `VerticalAlignment` устанавливается за счет свойства `VerticalContentAlignment`. Теперь вопрос - зачем править шаблон, если можно просто написать `<Button VerticalContentAlignment = "Stretch">`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ изначально смутило, но в приведённом коде в вопросе пример когда эти свойства не работают. На скриншоте https://skr.sh/sKit2rHtwSm?a видно что я выделил вложенную grid и она не занимает весь доступный размер, а только растягивается по мере наполнения. Следующий ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/856239/386256 подтолкнул попробовать это решение

Comment: Vertical**Content**Alignment и Horizontal**Content**Alignment. Не то установили, не тот результат получили.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ действительно так, я попробовал ваш совет, таблица приняла все доступное место. Спасибо)